# I want if else condition in my sql

Tags: mysql

i have a column in my sql table. if value is 1 then it should return admin asset else non admin asset. this is my sql code.

```
select asset_master_id,
    am_name as aname,
    am_serial_number as number,
    (CASE adm_admin_flag
        WHEN 1
        THEN "Admin Asset"
        ELSE "Non Admin Asset"
    END AS am_admin_flag)
FROM asset_master;
```

I tried above code but did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CASE syntax is wrong.

```
   SELECT 
     CASE 
      WHEN am_admin_flag = 1 
      THEN "Admin Asset"
      ELSE "Non Admin Asset"
     END AS am_admin_flag
    FROM 
     asset_master
```